# place column names of subplots in plotly on top of first row instead at bottom of last row

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Here is my code,

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv('data256.csv')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='graph-type',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Sunburst', 'value': 'sunburst'},
            {'label': 'Barplot', 'value': 'barplot'}
        ],
        value='sunburst'
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='zone',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Zones'].unique()],
        value='National'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graph')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('zone', 'style'),
    Input('graph-type', 'value'))
def toggle_zone_dropdown(graph_type):
    if graph_type == 'sunburst':
        return {'display': 'none'}
    else:
        return {'display': 'block'}

@app.callback(
    Output('indicator-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('graph-type', 'value'),
    Input('zone', 'value'))
def update_graph(graph_type, zone):
    if graph_type == 'sunburst':
        fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['Zones', 'Product', 'Indicator', 'Metric'], values='Value')
    else:
        dff = df[df['Zones'] == zone]
        fig = px.bar(dff, x='Product', y='Value', color='Metric', barmode='group', facet_row='Indicator')
        fig.update_layout(height=800)
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

it produces dashboard like this figure

[image]

The yellow highlighted text are to be placed in green highlighted areas. I tried following modification to code:

```py
fig.update_layout(height=800,
    xaxis=dict(
        side='top'
    )
)
```

however it produced following dashboard

[image]

As you can see the text appears in the gap between third and forth row, which is very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one x axis per row, from bottom to top : `xaxis`, `xaxis2`, `xaxis3`, `xaxis4`.

You want to remove the title and tick labels from `xaxis`, and apply them on `xaxis4` :

```py
fig.update_layout(
    height=800,
    xaxis=dict(
        title=None,
        showticklabels=False
    ),
    xaxis4=dict(
        side='top',
        showticklabels=True,
        title=dict(text='Product')
    )
)
```

Comment: I can't seam to get rid of facet labels in each row, though I moved indicators to left of each row replacing the word Value with the following code, before your suggestion in the graph_update function.
```python
        for i, indicator in enumerate(dff["Indicator"].unique()[::-1]):
            fig.update_yaxes(title_text=indicator, row=i + 1, col=1, tickangle=-0)
```

sorry could not make comment look better (like code in question)